# HashSet in Java - Comparison and hashkeys

Tags: java, queue, hashset

I know that the HashSet.contains() method uses the .equals method to check equality as in it checks the pointer to see whether they're equal.

I need it to check the actual object at the pointer for equality - in my specific case, I need to see whether a "Node" being opened (an int[] array) already exists in the HashSet. This is essential for my search algorithm so that the implementation of my Bi-directional Iterative Deepening Search isn't as naive.

I'd still like linear search time if possible, or perhaps I should use a different class?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but why don't you just get() it, if it's already in a hashset? This will be O(1) if the hashset isn't too full

Comment: @j13r: The OP wants to use `contains()`, which checks using `equals()`.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no .get() for Java HashSets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference equality is just the default implementation of .equals().  You can put your arrays in a wrapper class that overrides equals and hashCode to check the contents.  NB: In order for this to work the *contents must not change* after you put them in the set.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IntArrayNode {

private int[] array;

public IntArrayNode(int[] array) {
  this.array = array;
}

//getter and setter

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj != null && obj instanceof IntArrayNode) {
    return Arrays.equals(this.array, ((IntArrayNode) obj).array);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

public int hashCode() {
  return Arrays.hashCode(this.array);
}
}
```

Comment: Quick question to your answer - so the .equals() method invoked by .contains() is the .equals method for the type being searched?

Comment: Yes, if you make a `Set<IntArrayNode> set = new HashSet<IntArrayNode>();`  then when you do `set.contains(someIntArrayNode);`  it will use your equals().

Comment: `instanceof` evaluates to false if obj is null, so there is not need for the extra check. On the other hand a good initial check could be if obj == this, in whose case you can immediatelly return true.

Comment: true, was rattling it off fast because my cheese burger was about to burn :) will make it more standard

Comment: More like 
`if(obj == this) return true; 
if(obj instanceof IntArrayNode) //comparison code`?

Answer (score 0):

If your object implements the `equals` method, you can do whatever comparison you need to do to determine if two of your `Node` objects are unique.

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* workaround would be `Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<E, Boolean>())` (as a substitute for `HashSet`), which doesn't require doing any wrapping of your elements or anything.

Comment: Good idea, but I was using a wrapper class anyway and I didn't use it in the example for the sake of generality.